# Wicket:: add custom attribute to <li> element

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-6, wicket-1.6, wicketstuff

how can I add a **custom attribute** to an html list element?
I tried the following but got markup exception:

```
WebMarkupContainer con = new WebMarkupContainer("Temp");
con.add(new AttributeAppender("note",true, new Model<String>("Alpha")));
add(con);
```

HTML:

```
<li class="segment" wicket:id="Temp">Data Usage</li>
```

Any suggestions for custom attributes?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code seems ok. What exception are you getting? Is the code working without `con.add(new AttributeAppender(...))`?

Comment: at org.apache.wicket.markup.markupstream.throwmarkupexception(MarkupStream.java:526)
at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1435)
at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1554)
at org.apache.wicket.Page.onRender(Page.java:876)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.onRender(Webpage.java:142)
at org.apache.wicket.Component.render.(Component.java:2306)
at org.apache.wicket.Page.onRender(Page.java:1010)

Comment: you're right Andrej code is working fine. Exception is raised due to some other markup. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use valid markup (note the closing **li** tag):

```
<li class="segment" wicket:id="Temp">Data Usage</li>
```

Comment: That was missing !! but still same issue on custom attributes